# Generic mapping func with array of object and object to object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mapping

I would like to create generic mapping either input data will be array of objects or just object. In one case I use reduce for obj to obj mapping in other variant `array.map`.

in mapData should be returned [{..},{..}] - mapped array of objs
in mapSelectedItem should be returned {..}- mapped single obj

Current behaviour: duplicate code, same mapping for both cases 
Expected behaviour: one func or more easiest way to do this.
ecpected result:

```
{
  title: `${uiData.first_name} ${uiData.last_name}`,
 subTitle: `${uiData.city}`, 
 id: uiData.id
}


const fake = [
    {
        city: 'TOLEDO',
        first_name: 'Bob',
        id: 5,
        last_name: 'KHALIL',
    },
    {
        city: 'TOLEDO',
        first_name: 'Boby',
        id: 6,
        last_name: 'KHALIL',
    },
    {
        city: 'TOLEDO',
        first_name: 'Boby',
        id: 7,
        last_name: 'KHALIL',
    }
];

export function mapData(uiData) {
    return uiData.map(result => ({
        title: `${result.first_name} ${result.last_name}`,
        subTitle: `${result.city}`,
        id: result.id
    }));
}

export function mapSelectedItem(uiData) {
    return Object.keys(uiData).reduce(prev => {
        return {
            ...prev,
            title: `${uiData.first_name} ${uiData.last_name}`,
            subTitle: `${uiData.city}`, 
            id: uiData.id
        };
    }, {});
}
```

Comment: Why not use the callback of `map` inside `mapSelectedItem`?

Comment: in mapData should be returned [{..},{..}] - mapped array of objs
in mapSelectedItem should be returned {..}- mapped single obj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `reduce`. Move the current callback of `map` to the `mapSelectedItem` function. Then, use `mapSelectedItem` as a callback of map in `mapData`

```js
const mapSelectedItem = uiData => ({
  title: `${uiData.first_name} ${uiData.last_name}`,
  subTitle: `${uiData.city}`,
  id: uiData.id
})

const mapData = uiData => uiData.map(mapSelectedItem);

// array of objects
console.log(
  mapData([{city:"TOLEDO",first_name:"Bob",id:5,last_name:"KHALIL",},{city:"TOLEDO",first_name:"Boby",id:6,last_name:"KHALIL"}])
)

// single object
console.log(
  mapSelectedItem({city:"TOLEDO",first_name:"Bob",id:5,last_name:"KHALIL",})
)
```